# iphone:Urban airship libUAirship-1.1.1.a error occurs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, urbanairship.com

I am implementing Push notification(urban airship) in my application. I have written the code and also added the necessary framework including libUAirship-1.1.1.a but it shows me following error.

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag", referenced from:
      +[UA_ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in libUAirship-1.1.1.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
  "_UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass", referenced from:
      +[UA_ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in libUAirship-1.1.1.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
  "_kUTTagClassFilenameExtension", referenced from:
      +[UA_ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in libUAirship-1.1.1.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
  "_kUTTagClassMIMEType", referenced from:
      +[UA_ASIHTTPRequest mimeTypeForFileAtPath:] in libUAirship-1.1.1.a(UA_ASIHTTPRequest.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can't understand why this error generated.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this document it may help you : [Push Notification Client Library](http://urbanairship.com/docs/apns_test_client.html#set-up-a-new-application)